# NodeJS Express - 404/400 Responses

Tags: express

I am just wondering if 404/400 Responses in a node express app is consider an error and if it will be caught by the error handling middle ware?

I had a hard time finding this in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP/1.1, a response code of 400 or higher is considered an error.

However, Express error handling only deals with *programming* errors, not HTTP errors. If your app detects an error condition and sends back a 400 or 404 response, Express doesn't care (i.e. it won't call the error handler).

Comment: Strange.. I am using express-mung to transform my response, but when I return a `res.status(400);` it does not breakpoint to my middle ware :/

Comment: @nav https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mung#options (combined with this: https://github.com/richardschneider/express-mung/blob/8d795a134d3e0fc0a4ab643032b581f95319bb71/index.js#L30-L31). So `express-mung` considers all responses with a status code of 400 or higher as an error, and you need to set `mungError : true` if you want it to catch those.